# Evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel for Standard visiting visa

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I am from Indian. My parents are staying in India but I am working in China. I need to apply for UK Visa from China. Do I need to submit any documents as a support for "evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel"? If so what kind of document I suppose to ?

Comment: If you are working in China and do not have family members living with you, then you probably do not need to submit any such documents.

Comment: @Kanchana C Since you are working in China, and assuming you intend to return there after your planned visit to the U.K., evidence of family members remaining in India is not relevant. What is relevant is strong evidence to prove your ties to China and demonstrate that your intention to return there is credible. If on the other hand you intend to go back to India, then you should provide evidence of your family ties there, eg copy of your birth certificate and your parents’ passports/electoral photo ID card/driving licence etc